# Text not displaying in FLTK Text Display when inside a Wizard

Tags: user-interface, rust, fltk

I'm writing a GUI program with fltk-rs, and I hit something I can't understand. The `text::TextDisplay` widget works perfectly well until I put it inside a `group::Wizard`, which I'm doing so I can swap between it and another widget eventually. I've made a small example:

```
use fltk::{prelude::*, *};

fn main() -> Result<(), FltkError> {
    let app = app::App::default();
    let mut win = window::Window::default()
                                 .with_size(512, 512)
                                 .with_label("Blackout");
    let mut col = group::Flex::default()
                              .with_type(group::FlexType::Column)
                              .size_of_parent();
    let mut text_group = group::Wizard::default();
    let mut label1 = text::TextDisplay::default();
    let mut label2 = text::TextDisplay::default();
    let mut text_buf = text::TextBuffer::default();

    text_group.end();
    text_buf.append("lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");
    label1.set_buffer(text_buf.clone());
    label1.set_color(enums::Color::Dark1);
    label2.set_buffer(text_buf.clone());
    label2.set_color(enums::Color::Dark3);

    let mut button = button::Button::default().with_label("Switch");
    let mut showing_first = true;

    button.set_callback(move |_| {
        if showing_first { text_group.next(); }
        else { text_group.prev(); }

        showing_first = !showing_first;
    });

    let mut label3 = text::TextDisplay::default();
    
    label3.set_buffer(text_buf.clone());
    col.set_size(&mut button, 50);
    col.end();
    win.end();
    win.show();

    app.run()
}
```

The layout is in a vertical column that has (top to bottom) 3 direct children: a wizard, a button, and a text display. The wizard contains two text displays with different background colors. The button switches the wizard between them.

[image: switching between text displays works]

Switching the wizard between the two text displays appears to work (you can see the background color change), but unlike the one below the button, the two inside the wizard don't display their text. Why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certain group widgets don't pass parent layouts to their children, since this allows creating custom widgets with their own custom layout, think of a `<div>` in html terms.

So even though you pass a default() size for text_group (a Wizard), and this is resized by the parent Flex widget, the TextDisplay widgets, are children of the Wizard, not of the Flex. You can pass an arbitrary size to the text_group, this will be resized by the Flex anyway, and pass the text display widgets the Wizard's size:

```rust
    let mut text_group = group::Wizard::new(0, 0, 400, 400, None);
    let mut label1 = text::TextDisplay::default().size_of_parent();
    let mut label2 = text::TextDisplay::default().size_of_parent();
    let mut text_buf = text::TextBuffer::default();

    text_group.end();
```

Comment: That's interesting, thank you! I'm not sure I understand why this works, though. `size_of_parent` will make the TextDisplays follow the Wizard's size, which is itself set by the Flex, that makes sense. Why does an arbitrary size need to be passed in? Shouldn't `size_of_parent` alone (one of the things I tried myself) be enough to make the TextDisplays follow the Wizard's size? Or will the "command" be ignored unless the parent has a defined size at the time of calling. Also odd that the background colors for those widgets displayed at full size in my example then

Comment: It’s a particularity you can say. Before the window is shown, SomeWidget::default() sets the size to 0. It’s fine for Flex children since it will resize the children. But as far as the TextDisplay knows at that point is that the parent’s size is 0, so their size is also 0, and they are not resized automatically by the Flex since their parent is the Wizard.